# How to generate apks with different AndroidManifest.xml using Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

The build.gradle which I wrote is below:

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
         hip {
            manifest.srcFile 'hip/AndroidManifest.xml'
}
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

But I can find only the main one apks,not hip one.

Answer (score 0):

You must define product flavors :

```
android {
  ...
  productFlavors {
    hip {
        manifest.srcFile 'hip/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }

    main {
        manifest.srcFile '<where you put the other one>/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
```

Comment: why i can't set manifest.srcFile use '=' like other's do(e.g.:res.srcDirs = ['res'])